# Change checked value in datagridview checkbox cell based on dialog result

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have a situation here. I have CheckBox column in DataGridView and it is checked by default (when the form loads). Now I have MessageBox for the confirmation that will pop up when someone wants to uncheck 
CheckBox. So when the DialogResult returns cancel, it should come back to normal state (previous value) and once DialogResult returns OK, it should uncheck. I have tried many cell events which doesn't suit my situation all will fire after cell change its value. I want to trigger snippets before it changes the value.

I tried several events (CellValueChanged,CellContentClick, CellBeginEdit, CellClicked,CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged etc.) but nothing worked.

Comment: which cell events have you tried already? can you also include code of your best attempt?

Comment: do you want your dialog to appear only for the very first time a check box is clicked ? or on every click ?

Comment: @Kapoor it should be for every click.

Answer (score 0):

`CellBeginEdit` works for me:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    bool oldVal = (bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;

    DialogResult r = MessageBox.Show("Really?", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
    if (r == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = !oldVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but sad part is it will work only for the first click. It will not work for the later multiple clicks..can I get the solution for that also..

Comment: It works for mutiple clicks. However, when you first click the checkbox the row is in edit mode. Not until you left the current row and the changes are "committed" it is possible to enter CellBeginEdit event with checkbox again. If yo uwant it on every click - what would be very annoying for the use imho  - you have to use on of the Mouse events

Comment: @ Alex B., If there is only one row in datagridview and changes are committed it wont trigger that event. I tried with it.